# jquery validation does not working correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

jquery validation does not work correctly. When I deleted image validation it works correctly
I am sure that problem form image, but how can I fix it?
Is there a method to do it?

```
 $("#admin_changes").validate({
            errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
                if (element.hasClass("image-validate")) {
                    error.insertAfter('#image-lable');
                }
                else{
                    error.insertAfter(element);
                }
            },
            ignore: "",
            rules:{
                image:{
                    required: false,
                    extension: "png|jpe?g",
                    filesize : 300000,
                },
                name:{
                    required: true,
                    //maxlength: 50
                },

                login:{
                    //maxlength: 50,
                    required: true,
                },


            },
            messages:{
                name: {
                    required: "<p style='color:red'>please enter name<p>",
                    //maxlength: "<p style='color:red'>text should be shorter than 50<p>",
                },
                login: {
                    required: "<p style='color:red'>please enter login<p>",
                    //maxlength: "<p style='color:red'>text should be shorter than 50<p>",
                },

                image:{
                    extension: "<p style='color:red'>file must be png, jpg or jpeg<p>",
                    filesize: "<p style='color:red'>file is very big<p>",
                 }    
            }    
        });
```

When I run this code, validation das do not work until I uploaded an image , but when I deleted the validation for the image all validations started work

Comment: try changing the value of extension to a comma separated string as 'png,jpeg,jpg'

Comment: `does not work correctly` does not tell us anything.  What is the problem?  What happened, and what did you expect to happen? Are you getting error msgs?

Comment: When I run this code, validation das do not work until I uploaded an image , but when I deleted the validation for the image all validations started work.